# Finding the Lagrangian dual problem for a quadratic programm

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, duality

I've problems to find the Lagrangian dual problem to
\begin{align*}
\min \limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}  \; \frac{1}{2} x^{ T} Q x + q^{T} x    \\
\text{s.t.} \quad
Ax &=b     \\
x &\geq 0
\end{align*}

Taking the definition, I get:
\begin{align*}
\max \limits_{(\lambda, s)} \,( \inf \limits_x \; \frac{1}{2} x^{ T} Q x + q^{T} x - \lambda x + s (Ax-b) )  \\
\text{s.t.} \quad
\lambda\geq 0
\end{align*}

I would like to have a form, where I can recognize the following equation:
\begin{align*}
 Qx +A^T \lambda +s = c 
\end{align*}
and in the case of Q = 0 the dual linear program.

Could someone help me?

Thanks
Martin